# Django: Querying two tables based on URL slug

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have created a database of music Producers and their Samples.

```
class Producers(models.Model):
    producer_id = models.AutoField(db_column='Producer_ID', primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    slug = models.SlugField()
    name = models.TextField(db_column='Name')  # Field name made lowercase.
    info = models.TextField(db_column='Info', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'producers'


class Samples(models.Model):
    song_id = models.AutoField(db_column='Song_ID', primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Producers, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Producer_ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    artist = models.TextField(db_column='Artist')  # Field name made lowercase.
    title = models.TextField(db_column='Title')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'samples'
```

I have set up Slug Urls directing to the according Producer. ex) "producers/j-dilla/"

I want each producer's bio to list their samples.

Tried utilizing

```
def bio(request, slug):
   producer_list = Producers.objects.all().filter(slug=slug)
   samples_list = Samples.objects.all()
   queryset = sorted(
            chain(producer_list, samples_list),
            key=lambda instance: instance.producer_id)
```

```
{% for sample in queryset %}
                    <li>
                        <span>Artist: {{ sample.artist }}</span> <br/>
                        <span>Title: {{ sample.title }}</span> <br/>
                        <span>Title: {{ sample.producer_id }}</span> <br/>
                        <hr/>
                    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

returns the entire database of samples.

Comment: Do you expect multiple producers to have the same slug? Your query implies that.

Comment: no they each have their own slug, sorry, which part of the code implies that? Maybe I an go from there

Comment: `.filter(slug=slug)` will return a QuerySet. If you use `.get()` or `get_object_or_404()` you will have only the desired object. Also, you might find [following relationships backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) useful to read.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you, I will read this before moving further.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone down the line. This queried the producer table for slug=slug, than filtered the samples table with producer_id. Seems almost like a SQL join statement.

```
    producer = Producers.objects.get(slug = slug)
    queryset = Samples.objects.filter(producer=producer.producer_id)
```